# keyboard not getting fit in view in landscape mode running on ios 5.0 and 4 inch screen

Tags: ios5, uikeyboard, iphone-5

Hey i am  developing an app for iphone5 (4 inch screen) everything works fine but when i run my app on iOS 5.0 and rotate to landscape mode , keyboard does not fit entire screen ,
Adding a screenshot. it happens with all keyboard type.

Is there a way to deal with this bug at our end or it needs to be fixed by apple guys only.
I am running app on simulator, so if anybody have iphone 5 with ios 5.0 installed , please check, Does that issue persists on device also ?
[image]